# pySpark How to change the column names using sqlContext.sql

Tags: csv, dataframe, pyspark

I run a command using sqlContext.sql 
The result is a dataframe but the column names did not reflect what I am trying to represent

```
test=("SELECT SUBJECT_ID ,DRUG, COUNT(*), SUM(DOSE_VAL_RX) AS Dosage\
from sel_meds_pats_icustays \
GROUP BY SUBJECT_ID , DRUG ")
test_df= sqlContext.sql(tot_icustay_meds_pat_query).withColumnRenamed('_c1','count')
```

The resulting Dataframe show this way... eventhough I tried to rename the columns.

```
 [Row(SUBJECT_ID=6, DRUG=u'Syringe (IV Room)', count(1)=3, sum(CAST(DOSE_VAL_RX AS DOUBLE))=3.0), Row(SUBJECT_ID=13, DRUG=u'Potassium Chloride', count(1)=2, sum(CAST(DOSE_VAL_RX AS DOUBLE))=60.0), Row(SUBJECT_ID=36, DRUG=u'Cisatracurium Besylate', count(1)=1, sum(CAST(DOSE_VAL_RX AS DOUBLE))=100.0), Row(SUBJECT_ID=36, DRUG=u'Heparin Flush CVL  (100 units/ml)', count(1)=1, sum(CAST(DOSE_VAL_RX AS DOUBLE))=1.0), Row(SUBJECT_ID=36, DRUG=u'Lansoprazole Oral Disintegrating Tab', count(1)=1, sum(CAST(DOSE_VAL_RX AS DOUBLE))=30.0)]
```

I also tried using ALIAS in the SELECT statement and it also does not show

Also how do I save this results to a csv file..

Answer (score 0):

You can use below mention three approach for same:-

```
1) sqlContext.sql("SELECT SUBJECT_ID, DRUG, COUNT(*) total_subject, SUM(DOSE_VAL_RX) dosage\
                     from sel_meds_pats_icustays \
                     GROUP BY SUBJECT_ID , DRUG ").show()


2) sqlContext.sql("SELECT SUBJECT_ID, DRUG, COUNT(*), SUM(DOSE_VAL_RX) \
                     from sel_meds_pats_icustays \
                     GROUP BY SUBJECT_ID , DRUG ").withColumnRenamed("_c0", "total_subjects").withColumnRenamed("_c1", "dosage").show()

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
3) sqlContext.sql("SELECT SUBJECT_ID, DRUG, COUNT(*), SUM(DOSE_VAL_RX) \
                     from sel_meds_pats_icustays \
                     GROUP BY SUBJECT_ID , DRUG ").select("SUBJECT_ID", "DRUG", col("_c0").alias("total_subjects"), col("_c1").alias("dosage")).show()
```

Save To CSV:-

```
# First Install This Package com.databricks.spark.csv 
df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("testing.csv")
```